# How to print out just the information without the rest of blank document

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am very new to programing and this is my first project. I am trying to print out just the information shown in the screen shots, which do print out. Which is the "Caplugs West" "PN" "QTY" and "B#". This print fine going to a normal printer and normal paper size. But I am trying to print this information to a label and when I print it to the label it prints out the the whole page even the bottom blank part of it with no information. I just want to print the information and that's it. I do not want to print the header and footer and I do not want to print the blank part of the page. Is there a way to do this?

[image]

[image]

here is my Index View Model

```
@model NavisionStore.WebUI.Models.PrintIndexViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Bag Labels: Your Print";
}

<h2>Caplugs West</h2>
<table>
    <tbody>
        @foreach(var line in Model.Print.Lines) {
            <tr>
                <td>PN: @line.Product.PartName</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>QTY: @line.Product.Quantity</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>B# @line.Product.BagNumber</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <p align="center" class="actionButtons noprint">
        <a href="@Model.ReturnUrl">Continue shopping</a>
    </p>
```

Her is my Site.css

```
body {
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    color: #232323;
    background-color: #fff;
}

header, footer, nav, section {
    display: block;
}


/* Styles for basic forms
-----------------------------------------------------------*/
fieldset {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 0 1.4em 1.4em 1.4em;
    margin: 0 0 1.5em 0;
}

legend {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
}

textarea {
    min-height: 75px;
}

.editor-label {
    margin: 1em 0 0 0;
}

.editor-field {
    margin: 0.5em 0 0 0;
}


/* Styles for validation helpers
-----------------------------------------------------------*/
.field-validation-error {
    color: #f00;
}

.field-validation-valid {
    display: none;
}

.input-validation-error {
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    background-color: #fee;
}

.validation-summary-errors {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #f00;
}

.validation-summary-valid {
    display: none;
}

BODY { 
    font-family: Cambria, Georgia, "Times New Roman"; margin: 0; 
}

DIV#header DIV.title, DIV.item H3, DIV.item H4, DIV.pager A {
    font: bold 1em "Arial Narrow", "Franklin Gothic Medium", Arial;
}

DIV#header {
    background-color: #444;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #111;
    color: white;
}
DIV#header DIV.title {
        font-size: 2em;
        padding: .6em;
}
DIV#content {
    border-left: 2px solid gray;
    margin-left: 9em;
    padding: 1em;
}
DIV#categories {
    float: left;
    width: 8em;
    padding: .3em;
}

DIV.item {
    border-top: 1px dotted gray;
    padding-top: .7em;
    margin-bottom: .7em;
}
    DIV.item:first-child {
        border-top: none;
        padding-top: 0;
}
    DIV.item H3 {
        font-size: 1.3em;
        margin: 0 0 .25em 0;
}
    DIV.item H4 {
        font-size: 1.1em;
        margin: .4em 0 0 0;
}

DIV.pager {
    text-align: right;
    border-top: 2px solid silver;
    padding: .5em 0 0 0;
    margin-top: 1em;
}
DIV.pager A {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    color: #666;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 .4em 0 .4em;
}
    DIV.pager A:hover {
        background-color: silver;
    }
    DIV.pager A.selected {
        background-color: #353535;
        color: white;
    }

/*This styles the left menu pane*/
DIV#categories A {
    font: bold 1.1em "Arial Narrow","Franklin Gothic Medium",Arial;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: .6em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
}
    DIV#categories A.selected {
        background-color: #666;
        color: white;
    }
    DIV#categories A.hover {
        background-color: #CCC;
    }
    DIV#categories A.selected:hover {
        background-color: #666;
    }

FORM {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
DIV.item FORM {
    float: right;
}
DIV.item INPUT {
    color: white;
    background-color: #333;
    border: 1px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
}

H2 {
    margin-top: 0.3em;
}
.actionButtons A, INPUT.actionButtons {
    font: .8em Arial;
    color: white;
    margin: .5em;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: .15em 1.5em .2em 1.5em;
    background-color: #353535;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
@media print {
    .noprint {
        display: none;
    }
}
@media print {
    #header, #categories, .actionButtons {
        display: none;
    }

    DIV#content {
        border-left: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Look into making a separate style sheet for print. http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".